# How to restart services from the procfile?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following procfile used by AWS ElasticBeanstalk:

```
web: gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 1 --timeout 30 --graceful-timeout 35 --capture-output --worker-class eventlet wsgi:app
celery: celery --app wsgi.celery worker --concurrency 500 --pool eventlet
```

I had a bug on my code that I've fixed a few days ago, but even though the new change has been pushed (I can see other changes I made in between that are reflected on the `web` part), I still have bug notifications (from Sentry) that my previous bug occurs.

Debugging the issue at Sentry show the culprit code, and when searching on my current code, I can't find it (because I've fixed it), but still, the issue occurs.

I suspect that for some reasons, Elastic Beanstalk has not restarted - or taken into consideration - the new code for `celery` and is using the old one.

Is there a way to tell EB to restart/reload the `celery` worker (or even both) when deploying a new version?

I have some scripts implemented in the `.platform/hooks` so I can add one more to do that.

Comment: Did you restart it manually to verify if this fixes the problem. I think its always restarted after each deploy anyway.

Comment: How can I restart it manually? Do you mean the whole server?